# 3/4” Furring Strip Sufficient Holding Strength for French Cleat Wall?

Tags: screws, studs

I have 3/4” thick furring strips (1x2s) anchored to a concrete wall (very securely) that I am planning to put 1/2” plywood on for a French cleat wall. Will the 3/4” depth, using a 1.25” screw to secure the plywood, provide sufficient holding power?

The heaviest thing I have planned is 2 bikes hanging, one over the other. The cleats will be anchored through the plywood and into furring strips.

I have considered replacing strips with a sideways 2x4, which I know would do the trick. But that’s a lot of work and hardware if what I already have is likely strong enough.

Am I likely safe with a 3/4” depth, or am I a fool to dream?

Comment: that sounds like it will work.  what bad things will happen if it fails.

Comment: That’s basically where I am at now, since I want to move forward. Things are unlikely to tear off all at once, so I’ll have warning. But, even if, I’ll just end up with some bikes and maybe a mess of tools on the floor. Nothing that can’t be cleaned up and rehung when I go something thicker.

Comment: It sounds like you are questioning if attaching a 1/2" piece of plywood to a 3/4" thick rail for the other half of the cleat will be sufficient to support the weight of the bike. Is that what you're asking?